# How to search in String Array in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, algorithm, oop

I want to search in an Array, my code is this:

```
public class A
{   
    public String [] Names;
    public A( List<String> listSp)
        {
            Names = new String[listSp.size()];
            listSp.toArray(Names);
        }
      public int numberOfState(String s)
        {

            int counter = 0;
            while (Names[counter] != s)
            {
               counter ++;  
            }
            return counter;
            }
```

and use class A in this code :

```
public class Main extends Activity
{
...
   List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
   l.add("a");
   l.add("b");
      A objA = new A(l);
    int i = objA.numberOfState("b");
...
}
```

And when run application and use this part, has been show this error:

> Unfortunately,Main has been stopped

How I do?

Comment: you have an error here *while (Names[counter] != s* should be *while (Names[counter] != s)*

Comment: int i = objA.numberOfState("b");

Comment: @oop12 next time please put whatever comes after the line you posted (Unfortunately,Main has been stopped) so that we could see what exception was thrown and help you better.
In fact i would really love it if you can add it to this question.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a `for` loop or `String.equals()`?

Comment: Thanks,but my essue is this: the condition in while loop does not work.how i do?

Comment: you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is "out of bounds" you need check that the value of `counter` is smaller than that of your array length (or size).

your code should be this:

```
public int numberOfState(String s) {
  int counter = 0;
  while (Names[counter] != s && counter < Names.length) {
    counter ++;  
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: @oop12 you got some advance? Do you test my answer?